# Combining line and column chart messes up x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart like this:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "series": [{
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 2
    }, {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 2
    }],
    "type": "line"
  }],
  "chart": {
    "height": 300
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10
  },
});
```

[image: line chart]

and a column chart like this:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "series": [{
    "data": [{
      "x": 5,
      "y": 1
    }],
    "type": "column"
  }],
  "chart": {
    "height": 300
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10
  },
});
```

[image: column chart]

I would like to combine those. The columns are measured values and the line represents some kind of threshold.

My code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "series": [{
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 2
    }, {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 2
    }],
    "type": "line"
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "x": 5,
      "y": 1
    }],
    "type": "column"
  }],
  "chart": {
    "height": 300
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10
  },
});
```

What I expect it to look like:

[image: expected combined chart]

What it actually looks like:

[image: actual combined chart]

I originally thought this was a bug, so I created a bug report on [GitHub](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18782), but I was told this is working as expected.

I need the x-axis to be correct because I have other charts with matching x-axis ranges on the same page. How can I get the correct range and ticks?

If you want to play around with the issue, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwuqr7cy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `pointRange` for column series and to avoid padding of the X axis, set `pointPlacement` to `'on'`.

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPlacement: 'on',
      pointRange: 1
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tLugeoxz/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacemen

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

Answer (score 0):

a few weeks ago I ran into the same problem. I solved it by adding `pointRange: 1` to the column serie.

Full code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "series": [{
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 2
    }, {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 2
    }],
    "type": "line"
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "x": 5,
      "y": 1
    }],
    "type": "column",
    "pointRange": 1
  }],
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10
  }
});
```